# Changing Centreon graph y-axis scale for used disk space

Tags: monitoring, nagios, centreon

I am monitoring disk space use on Windows servers using the `check_nt` plugin (via the `check_nt_disk` command). This works just fine and I get some nice graphs as well.

The problem with the graph (storage template) is that the x-axis shows the disk space used rather than the total size of the disk, for example:

[image]

The check that is producing this data is effectively:

```
./check_nt -H 172.16.3.200 -p 12489 -s MyPassword -v USEDDISKSPACE -l d -w 80 -c 90
```

Which returns to nagios the following (I've split this over two lines on the pipe character):

```
d:\ - total: 19.55 Gb - used: 3.65 Gb (19%) - free 15.90 Gb (81%) | 
'd:\ Used Space'=3.65Gb;15.64;17.59;0.00;19.55
```

I know that the total disk space available is being recorded (`19.55`) but I don't know how to tweak the graph to use this as the y-axis scale.

Has anyone done this before?

I'm using Nagios 3.2.3 and Centreon 2.2 stable.

**Update:**

In reply to regilero, these are all the curves I have available:

[image]

These are all the templates:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Views>Graphs>Curves`, there you shoudl find your Curve 'd--Used-Space'. Edit this curve and check the box '**Print Max value**'.

In your line `3.65Gb;15.64;17.59;0.00;19.55` you have in fact `(value)(metric);(warn level);(crit level);(min level);(max level)`. So you need to graph as well the max value on this metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm looking at the graph curves but I don't see a curve called `d--Used-Space`. Is this something I need to create?

Comment: Yes, try to create it, this way you should get more control on the metric managed by Centreon. The name will may be as well 'd:\ Used Space', I'm not sure

Comment: I added a couple of screen grabs of what I see.

Comment: And, have you tried to create this Curve (the Add butonn on top)?

Comment: Yes I did, nothing changed. I am a bit baffled. :/

Comment: what is the name of the metric as seen in Administration>Options>Centstorage>Manage? If you change the color of your curve is it used on the graph?

Comment: Ok...the colour changes so that's a good start (the metric is called `d--Used-Space`). I made sure the `Storage` graph template has it's `Max` checkbox ticked and cleared the others. However it seems the problem is that it's taking the Max value from max disk space used reading rather than the total disk size.

Comment: I think I understand graphs a lot better now :) Anyway....the only way I can see to do this is to set the "Upper Limit" value in the graph template. This isn't ideal because if you have different disk sizes then you need a separate template for each one. It would be nice if the graphs could scale based on the Total Size. I might raise this as a feature request. Anyway thanks for the help.